# Android SDK 22 - SearchView rendering problems

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, searchview

We've just updated local **Android SDK** to new **[version 22](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2015/03/android-51-lollipop-sdk.html)**, and we are trying to update also our apps, but it seems to be a problem with *[SearchView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html)* rendering in layout Design view of *Android Studio*: everytime designer try to render a *SearchView* element, it throws an exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   android.content.res.TypedArray.hasValueOrEmpty(TypedArray.java:845)
>     at android.widget.SearchView.(SearchView.java:295)   at
>   android.widget.SearchView.(SearchView.java:258)   at
>   android.widget.SearchView.(SearchView.java:254)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:806)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)

This occours even if we create a new element from left toolbar in a new layout file.
Any idea?

[image: Rendering error]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <SearchView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/searchView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Edit

Change your android version on your designer preview into your current version depend on your Manifest. rendering problem caused your designer preview used higher API level than your current android API level.

---

It should work

Just change the api 22 to 21 in android xml layout

[image]

Comment: Even if this seems more an hack than a solution, it works. Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 2):

I voted up Davide comments. Error means searchIcon can not be null (why?).

This works to compile at Studio with api 22, but forces you to select an icon. The example is one of 2 defaults at android (none as cool as searchview default), you can always have your custom one...

Here the snippet.

```
        <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:searchIcon="@android:drawable/ic_search_category_default"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />
```

Comment: Not even with your snippet seems to work in layout Design, we get the same rendering error.

Answer (score 1):

Found this in the [source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-mr1-release/core/java/android/widget/SearchView.java). It's the dereference of `a` that fails in the evaluation.

```
    final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs, R.styleable.SearchView, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

    [...]

    // Prior to L MR1, the search hint icon defaulted to searchIcon. If the
    // style does not have an explicit value set, fall back to that.
    if (a.hasValueOrEmpty(R.styleable.SearchView_searchHintIcon)) {
        mSearchHintIcon = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.SearchView_searchHintIcon);
    } else {
        mSearchHintIcon = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.SearchView_searchIcon);
    }
```

Try setting the styled attributes?

Comment: What do you mean?
We've tried adding
`android:searchHintIcon="@drawable/ic_icon"  android:searchIcon="@drawable/ic_icon"`
to *SearchView* without any good result :-(

Comment: We've also tried adding a _style_ attribute to _SearchView_ element and relative `android:searchHintIcon/android:searchIcon` to _styles.xml_ without any fortune.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing **API level to higher** Rendering error will not be there.

[image]

It will resolve rendering issues