# cannot add SearchView in xml

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to add a `searchview` in a `layout` file, but it shows me some errors. I can't figure out what is wrong. My API Level is 14

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"        />
 <SearchView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></SearchView>

</LinearLayout>
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1l1X.png)

Comment: Please post your layout file containing the `SearchView`.

Comment: Maybe show us the errors you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in the IDE. ([Android SDK 22 - SearchView rendering problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005958/android-sdk-22-searchview-rendering-problems), [SearchView WITHOUT ACTIONBAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29467573/searchview-without-actionbar))

I think you can safely ignore this and wait for it to be fixed by Google.