# SearchView WITHOUT ACTIONBAR

Tags: java, android, searchview

I'm trying to create a SearchView in my android app, unfortunately almost all examples are about implementing the searchview in the actionbar. I have disabled the actionbar and I want to create the searchview inside a linear layout.

so I placed the searchview inside the linearlayout, as soon as you do that the xml preview will show "Rendering Problems":

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.content.res.TypedArray.hasValueOrEmpty(TypedArray.java:845)
at android.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:295)
at android.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:258)
at android.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:254)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor499.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:82)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:128)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:410)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:321)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:708)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:697)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:932)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:697)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.render(RenderService.java:816)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:646)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1700(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:82)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:589)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:584)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

but when I run the application it works just fine, any idea why is this nullpointerexception have been thrown?

this is my xml code:

```
<SearchView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/searchView"
android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
android:queryHint="Search"
android:searchIcon="@drawable/search_icon"
>
</SearchView>
```

and can you please provide me some example code on how to instantiate this searchview from java file so I can use it?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733460/android-providing-recent-search-suggestions-without-searchable-activity) is surely will answer to your question but different problem

Comment: Add your code snippet

Comment: What Y.S. said is actually right, there is no link to any code because I didn't do anything else. The problem is when I add the mentioned snippet (SearchView) this exception apears but the application works perfectly so I guess the problem is only with the IDE, maybe you're not using android studio that's why you haven't seen this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NullPointerException` is thrown by the IDE (not the application) when it tries to render the `SearchView`. There doesn't seem to be a problem with the `View` itself as such. If your app is working correctly, then just ignore it.

Comment: A NullPointerException can't be ignored! Just because works this doesn't meaning that the app is bug free :S
Someday can generated something worse with piling erros...

Comment: @Fernando Carvalho: The exception is thrown by **IntelliJ Idea, not by the app**. Can you understand the difference? IntelliJ Idea is itself a JAVA application, and like any other Java program it throws exceptions from time to time ... :)