# Search View Rendering Problems in API 22

Tags: java, android, rendering, searchview

Has anyone come across the **SearchView** rendering problem in **API 22**? If I switch the preview to API 21 (**using Android Studio**), there's no rendering problems.  I can't seem to figure out what the problem might be.

Here's my **xml** code for the **SearchView**:

```
<SearchView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layoutMode="clipBounds"
    android:id="@+id/eventSearchView"
    android:layout_gravity="start" />
```

This is the **rendering error**:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.content.res.TypedArray.hasValueOrEmpty(TypedArray.java:845)   
at android.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:295)   
at android.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:258)   
at android.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:254)   
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)   
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)   
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)   
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)   
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:806)   
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)   
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)   
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
```

Using **Android Studio 1.1.0**

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005958/android-sdk-22-searchview-rendering-problems

Comment: Thanks, changing the preview to a lower API level is what I've done. Not a perfect solution, but works.

Comment: Seems like changing to a lower API level is the only working solution as for now. :)