# Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar. My mistake or bug?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, android-appcompat, android-styles

I had the following rendering issue on all my layouts when using SDK 22 to preview them.

> Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.
>
> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: View_theme

In my case , the problem was `styles.xml`:

XML with rendering problem:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" />
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

XML without problem:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" />
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Notice how I had to add `@style/` in the parent reference. That seems to solve my problem (after a rebuild).

**Question, is this an error on my side, or a bug?** Many tutorials don't put it ([Including Official Android Page](https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html))

Gradle:

```
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 22
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
```

Final Note: I'm not using Toolbar.

Comment: see this [link][1] this may help you


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005958/android-sdk-22-searchview-rendering-problems/29822819#29822819

Comment: @Nilesh, in my case I'm able to use SDK 22, but only if I add `@style`. No need to downgrade to SDK 21.

Comment: Don't down grade the SDK only change api 22 to 21 in layout file .i.e preview 22 to 21

Comment: yeah, I meant that. :). By adding @style, I don't need to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT :**

Reading from another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870881/cant-find-theme-appcompat-light-for-new-android-actionbar-support).

If your activity extends `AppCompactActivity`, your parent theme should be

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" />
```

where as, if using `ActionBarActivity`, theme should be

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" />
```

> I think the difference is on purpose, and not a bug. Please feel free
>   to correct me if i am wrong as i cannot conferm the same from anywhere
>   yet.

**OLD :**

To use Toolbar as an action bar, the first thing you need to do is disable the decor provided action bar. The easiest way is to have your theme extend from Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar (or the light variant).

Use :

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
```

[From this post.](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/)

Comment: That's true only when I'm using "Toolbar", but I'm not.

Comment: What activity your class extends? ActionBarActivity or AppCompactActivity ?

Comment: Before the update, ActionBarActivity. Now I use AppCompactActivity.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity Reading from here, there seems to be a similer problem. AppCompactAct needs @style where as ActionBarAct does not. I think its not a bug. but strange. I will edit my ans

Comment: Well, I had the same trouble with ActionBarActivity

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, solution was as simple as

1. Add `@style` to the parent theme

   ```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
   ```
2. remove `android.support.v7.widget.` from `Toolbar`
3. move from `app:theme` to `android:theme`

   ```
   <Toolbar
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/toolbar"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
       android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
       android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
   ```

Comment: I need change Tabbar.axml, edit from "android.support.design.widget.TabLayout" to "com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout"