# Android Studio First Project Rendering Issues

Tags: android, android-studio

I just got android studio to make my first app, but when I created a test project,  the GUI didn't show up and says

Rendering Problems This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of Android Studio. Please update Android Studio (Details)

The details are below.

```
org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.RenderingException: This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of Android Studio. Please update Android Studio
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.LayoutLibraryLoader.load(LayoutLibraryLoader.java:90)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidTargetData.getLayoutLibrary(AndroidTargetData.java:159)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createTask(RenderService.java:164)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:475)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Please let me know how to fix the problem.

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005958/android-sdk-22-searchview-rendering-problems/29822819#29822819

Comment: How do you change it from 22 to 21?

Comment: in your xml file, see the answer agin i have updated it, with image

Answer (score 5):

Change your android version on your designer preview into your current version depend on your Manifest.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also modify the *Theme* at your Android Manifest

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

to something like:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```