# Android Studio rendering issue in design view

Tags: android, android-studio

When I open up my android studio, I do not see the image of any device in design view. Rather, an error shows up. I know there should be a device where we can do some drag and drop for GUI. How can this rendering problem be fixed?

[image]

Comment: select preview version 21 instead of 22

Comment: change app theme to any other theme like material light...

Comment: see this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005958/android-sdk-22-searchview-rendering-problems/29822819#29822819

Comment: Thanks guys. All of the solutions worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the Theme. There's the AppTheme tab if you can find. Change it to something other. Many other themes are available and will have different design schemes. Choose from them. The issue will be gone

Answer (score 0):

Add the resources in a library project as per http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

`>Section > Adding libraries with resources`

You then add the `android-support-v7-appcompat` library in your workspace and then add it as a reference to your app project.

[image]