# Android Studio: android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar can not be initiated

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-toolbar

I was developing a Toolbar for my android app and after creating `tool_bar.xml` file, the IDE is showing an error that following classes can not be initiated - android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

[image]

The full error details are

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/support/v7/appcompat/R$attr
    at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:191)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:413)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:105)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallback.loadView(LayoutlibCallback.java:177)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:214)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:142)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:413)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:321)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:497)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:485)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:894)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:485)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:590)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:480)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My `tool_bar.xml` file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Anyone has any idea why this is happening? I have tried invalidating cache and rebuilding and cleaning the project, and failed. Also switch to another API version also didn't worked out.

Comment: have tried changing api level  see the link . may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005958/android-sdk-22-searchview-rendering-problems/29822819#29822819

Comment: Had done that already but error still remain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, Finally I solved this issue. All I did was to update my Android Studio to latest stable build. Mine was on 1.2.1, latest stable one was 1.2.2. This solved the problem. But since I searched alot on this and having found that I am not the only one having this issue, I would like to list the possible solutions/things to try out incase this happens to anyone else :)

**1. Update your tools and IDE**

Sometimes it might be just a bug in your tools or IDE that could be fixed by updating to latest ver.

**2. Make sure you have added right dependencies to your gradle file**

Having not added the right dependencies or right version of dependencies could solve it. In this case @404notfound suggested some details on that on his answer. Check it out.

**3. Clean the project and then Gradle sync**

Also try rendering on a lower API level, to see if that works!

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to set app theme to something that inherit from Theme.Appcompat theme.

Edit:
If you have imported more support things add this to it:

```
compile ('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v7'
}
compile ('com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v7'
}
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```

It will prevent from importing wrong version of support library by other libs. Check if all support libs have same version.

Comment: Theme is already like that `
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">` !

Comment: The confusing part is that I have other projects files with same configuration & toolbar implemented which work fine!

Comment: Have you added supportv7 library for your project?

Comment: yes. In gradle file i have added dependency that `
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0`

Comment: Its's very strange, but I copied this xml, added same import, same theme and it worked like a charm...

Comment: yeh thats what I said indeed in my other projects this code works well.

Comment: I think that you should check your gradle files and check if all support things have same version. You can try adding this to ensure that library is not including support library itself. Example: compile ('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+') {
    exclude module: 'support-v7'
} and compile your v7 at the end

Comment: if it was an android studio problem, then it shouldn't have worked on other projects ha?

Comment: You mean I should add like this: ` compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0){ exclude module: 'support-v7' } `

Comment: No, I will update my answear for proper formatting look there in 2 minutes

Comment: I don't have any other import now it's only compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0

Comment: I just recalled that I had similar error, but changing version to +, helped, so maybe try changing compile to compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'

Comment: I done that and clean the project and build it again. No change.

Comment: Dont forget about gradle syncing

Comment: Since whenever I change gradle file, ide would prompt me to do that. So had done that too. I guess I will look it again fresh tomorrow morning, may be create a new project to test out.

Comment: updated to Android Studio 1.2.2(was on 1.2.1), voilà! Errors are gone :)

Comment: I will now add this and other possible solutions I came across and add it as answer. Thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1.** Clean and rebuild the project first.

**Step 2.** 'Sync Project with Gradle files' and update the layout.

If the problem is not fixed, reduce the rendering layout API version to a lower version.

Answer (score 0):

- Clean project
- Rebuild project
- Sync Gradle

it work for me