# SearchView rendering problems in Android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, searchview

I am asking this question here as I am not able to comment to answers yet. :)
I have a rendering problem of SearchView. And I believe its a bug in the new SDK. And I have gone through the solution provided to it in here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29822819/3458291

But my problem is that my Android Studio shows only 1 API option to select "API 22:Android 5.1.1". Why is it not showing other API options?

Found Solution: 
I believe one has to install the packages for the APIs first!!! Installing the packages from Android manager solved this issue. :)