# How do I get more options for APIs in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I just downloaded Android Studio 2, so I'm really new to the Android development side of things. The IDE is giving me a rendering issue:

```
Rendering Problems
    Failed to load the LayoutLib: com/android/layoutlib/bridge/Bridge : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (Details)
```

details returns this:

```
org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.RenderingException: Failed to load the LayoutLib: com/android/layoutlib/bridge/Bridge : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.LayoutLibraryLoader.load(LayoutLibraryLoader.java:90)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidTargetData.getLayoutLibrary(AndroidTargetData.java:180)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createTask(RenderService.java:164)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$7.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:514)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:337)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:327)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$3.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:271)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:286)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:244)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:234)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:352)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

And I believe the issue comes from the fact that my API isn't doing something correctly. When I select the dropdown menu to choose another API, all I get is 23 N Preview. How do I resolve this, and let me use the design tab of Android Studio?

I do have the JDK installed correctly (or so I think).

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005958/android-sdk-22-searchview-rendering-problems/29822819#29822819

Answer (score 0):

I too encountered almost the same problem in the previous version of Android Studio. This is what I did:

1. Check if JDK(7 or higher essentially) is installed properly on your computer.
2. Also try another preview option (ie.) lesser than what is shown on screen or try other screen orientations (ie.) portrait or landscape. Now, probably, you will be able to use both the design window and the xml coding page.

Happy programming!